# how to use PDF.js in react?

Tags: pdf.js

i installed pdfjs-dist in my project, then import it in my component, but the pdfjs is a promise, why?
my code:

```
import * as pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist";

const ChatDoc = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  console.log(pdfjs) // why pdfjs is a promise?

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};
```

pdfjs-dist version is 4.0.379
my project base on [ant design pro](https://pro.ant.design/)

i have try pdfjs.then(() => { console.log(1) })
but nothing happended.